# Jboss 6 Deployment, missing dependancy issue

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x

I'm in the process of learning EJB and am trying to deploy an example onto JBoss 6 for 5 days without much luck. The Maven build can downloaded here http://db.tt/pW9Vb99Q

I get the following error

```
    16:20:14,804 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/music-store-web]] Servlet /music-store-web threw load() exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.LevelMapping
at org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeLogger.log(BridgeLogger.java:173) [:1.0.0.GA]
```

Many thanks

Comment: can you check to see if there's a stack trace before this in the log? Sometimes a compile time error in your ear will cause some jboss components to have deployment errors making it less obvious what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the traceback.  It shows that you're not finding log4j.  This is almost certainly a configuration problem.

Here's one suggestion:

> http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?61560-Could-not-initialize-class-org.apache.log4j.LogManager
>
> Bootstrap listener for custom log4j initialization in a web
>   environment. Delegates to Log4jWebConfigurer (see its javadoc for
>   configuration details).
>
> WARNING:
>
> Assumes an expanded WAR file, both for loading the configuration file 
>   and for writing the log files. 
>   If you want to keep your WAR unexpanded or don't need application-specific 
>   log files within the WAR directory, don't use log4j setup within the 
>   application (thus, don't use Log4jConfigListener or Log4jConfigServlet). 
>   Instead, use a global, VM-wide log4j setup (for example, in JBoss) or JDK 1.4's
>   java.util.logging (which is global too).

ALSO:
Make sure you don't somehow have *two* versions of log4j.  Conflicting log4j*.jar files can also cause this error.

Comment: Thanks, cracked that one by trimming down on dependancies, it was a struts dependancy causing the problem. Getting another error now though - bummer